# Stadium House genre (similar to the KLF)

Tags: similar-artists, house

The band the KLF (a.k.a. the Justified Ancients of Mu-Mu, furthermore known as the JAMs) have described their music as "stadium house."  Is this a recognized genre?  If so, what are its characteristics and what other groups could be described as being in this genre?

I'm not specifically interested in the "huge amount of unauthorised samples" aspect of KLF music, as I know of some [really good](http://kleptones.com) [mashup](http://theairportdistrict.tumblr.com) [artists](https://soundcloud.com/bruneaux).  Rather, what other artists (currently active or retired) could be said to make [stadium house](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJqH5g67IiU) music?

Comment: Recommendation questions are off topic here, so I edited your question to highlight the genre definition aspect.  Feel free to revert if this doesn't match your intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Scooter from Germany. They are directly influenced by KLF and even covered/sampled them from time to time. They even use fake crowd noise in many of their songs.

Comment: They sound like if the KLF were Germans aimed for the British audience.

Answer (score 2):

Utah Saints were certainly considered proponents of the Stadium House subgenre too. In fact (from their Wikipedia entry): "They were described as "the first true stadium house band" by the KLF's Bill Drummond".

Comment: They sound less stereotypically stadium house than Scooter, but they are very listenable.